# How to add bookmark in chrome,firefox from javascript

Tags: jquery, bookmarks

Is there a way to add bookmark from javascript.
I saw many posts but most of them talk about adding manifest file and which we use in chrome extensions. Here I need it just for a website where in when i click on a link it should popup the bookmark option. I tried different ways didn't work.

I tried this below code which I found it stackoverflow but this seems to be outdated and doesn't work now.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#bookmarkme").click(function() {
    if (window.sidebar) { // Mozilla Firefox Bookmark
      window.sidebar.addPanel(location.href,document.title,"");
    } else if(window.external) { // IE Favorite
      window.external.AddFavorite(location.href,document.title); }
    else if(window.opera && window.print) { // Opera Hotlist
      this.title=document.title;
      return true;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

My workaround is

```
function bookmarkme() {
   alert("Press " + (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('mac') != -1 ?  'Command/Cmd' : 'CTRL') + "+D to bookmark page.");
   return;
};
```

I know, not very inventive.

Answer (score 0):

This was discussed on github. May have a look at [this conversation](https://gist.github.com/oilvier/70abd45d1f2ffc98b568).
All in all you have to lower your sight in browser compatibility due to a high effort.

Comment: There is not solutions, we need to use ctrl + d